# Ubuntu Slow - What architecture does the Windows Installer install?

Tags: installation, windows, performance, architecture

I feel absolutely limited by using Windows, and I need to switch to a Unix environment.
I once installed Red Hat on my laptop (screen + external monitor setup; 4GB ram; x64) and it worked fine, but I saw that the computer cluster that is the birthplace of my unix knowledge switched to Ubuntu, so naturally I follow.

To the point. When I installed Ubuntu onto my machine via the Windows Installer, it ran quite slow. Opening Firefox takes about 8-9 seconds, it freezes up often, unable to handle its own background processes.

I saw in a thread that, perhaps, it is running slow because the Windows Installer is installing an x64 version. Of course, my computer has had no performance issues in the past(except that time with the trojans but you know, no one is perfect ;) )

Anyways, I uninstalled Ubuntu, freeing up the max allocated memory it took up, and continue to be sad, trapped in my MS world with only a buggy Cygwin, any assistance is greatly appreciated! :)

Thanks
~Ben

Answer (score 1):

Wubi installs the architecture that matches the one you're running, so it should be x64.

That said, it's probably not the architecture that's your problem (I have no issues with x64 Ubuntu, even in virtual machines), but the fact that you installed it with Wubi. [According to Wikipedia, Wubi installs Ubuntu on a loopmounted device (basically, a disk image)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wubi_%28Ubuntu_installer%29) within the Windows partition, instead of its own partition. This means that the disk image itself is prone to fragmentation (thank you, NTFS), which will slow it down.

There are a few different paths you can take, depending on your circumstances, to be able to use Ubuntu:

1. **Wipe out Windows** If you don't need your Windows partition at all, just blow it up and replace it with Ubuntu and be done with it.
2. **Dual boot Windows and Ubuntu** If you have the drive space, the Ubuntu installer can repartition your hard drive and install Ubuntu next to Windows, allowing you access to both operating systems.
3. **Run Ubuntu in a Virtual Machine** If your computer is powerful enough, and you need Windows at the same time, then this may be the way to go. Grab VMWare, VirtualBox, or your favorite Virtual Machine program (I've had the best luck with VMWare, personally, for integration purposes), and install it there. That gives you a standalone Ubuntu install, while still allowing you access to Windows without having to restart the computer.
4. **Install Ubuntu on a USB thumb drive** If you need Windows for certain things, but can't install Ubuntu on drive for whatever reason, you can create a bootable USB drive with Ubuntu installed on it. Then, you can simply plug it in, tell your machine to boot from USB, and off you go! (This actually has two added bonuses - it's as fast as your USB version, which can make it super fast; and you can run it on any computer at any time. Though you are limited by the space available on your thumb drive, so keep your install lean and get a good-sized drive.)